# Can I run code in click handlers that have their buttons dynamically injected into the DOM with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, grid

My full code is at:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6EQFXL?p=preview

The "delete row" and "delete column" buttons are dynamically created. Right now when I click on them nothing happens. How can I get them to run the corresponding handlers? Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do (make a resizable and editable grid)?

Comment: It happens because you don't use `directive`. Create `directive` and post your dynamic HTML there with bindidng

Answer (score 1):

## Main Issue

The problem is that your creating the html for the button without compiling it through angularjs. You could just send this through the $compile service to get it to work but that's not the angular way. The better option would be to create a directive for tbody and put code there either as a template or in the compile phase of the directive. There's a great video by Misko Henvrey (lead engineer from angular) about creating directives at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqmeI5fZcho. Also you might want to check out the ng-grid created by the angular-ui team at https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid to get an idea of how to put together a semantic grid component.

## Side Issue

When trying to think in angular you really need to start thinking of the functionality you need and architecting a solution for the functionality (e.g. the directive (s)). What you've done in this question instead is thinking the traditional javascript way (nothing wrong with that in general), which is to say ok I'm limited by what html gives me and I need to tie my javascript in to the stuff I'm given through hooks on classes and ID's. I highly recommend taking a look at ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) to get a more complete view of angular vs jquery/traditional javascript.